# Inter module communication with Pub-Sub in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface, argparse, publish-subscribe

I am a developing a Command Line Interface(CLI) application in Python. It consists of an entry point *cli.py* which defines a CLI parser using  *argparse*. There is also a *commands* package which contains several modules that extend the CLI parser with their respective sub-commands

```
app
|    cli.py
|____commands
     |    __init.py__
     |    sub_command1.py
     |    sub_command2.py
```

My initial approach was to define a function *register_subcommand* in each sub-command module and call each of them in *cli.py*. Since this was a bit verbose and I wanted to be able to plugin a sub-command without changing other files, I opted for a different approach

I am currently using Pub-Sub to register the CLI for sub-commands and to invoke them. This has the benefit of being able to just drop in a sub-module. However, now importing the modules looks weird as the import is unused and is only for side effects (registering sub-modules).

```
#  cli.py (this is just a template, not working code)
import app.commands # unused import

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
publish_event('register_subcommand', parser)
args = parser.parse_args()
publish_event('execute_subcammnd', args)

# sub-command1.py
@subscribe('register_sub_modules')
def register_subcommand(parser):
    pass

@subscribe('execute_subcammnd')
def execute_subcommand(args):
    pass

# __init__.py
# Imports all sub_command modules in the package
```

Is this is a bad practice in Python in general? What are the downsides? Any better designs to achieve this?

Comment: Https://github.com/schollii/pypubsub?